# How can I use dtoverlay=pwm

Tags: pwm

I have tried the `dtoverlay=pwm` but couldn't seem to get PWM working.
It puts the pin/s in PWM mode and creates `/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0` but no signal.

The `dtoverlay` description states *4) Currently the clock must have been enabled and configured by other means.* but I have failed to find any "other means" or documentation explaining how to get it to generate a PWM signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently discovered some kernel documentation [Pulse Width Modulation (PWM) interface](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.10/driver-api/pwm.html)

Like much kernel documentation this is inscrutable. It states *This API controls both the PWM period/duty_cycle config and the enable/disable state.*

I will attempt to explore this in future but there is also [Using PWMs with the sysfs interface](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.10/driver-api/pwm.html#using-pwms-with-the-sysfs-interface) which enabled me to get it working.

---

1. Load the overlay `pwm` (or `pwm-2chan`) with `dtoverlay=pwm` in
   `config.sys` or on-the-fly with `sudo dtoverlay pwm`
   You can use `sudo dtoverlay pwm pin=12 func=4` to use GPIO12 rather than the default GPIO18.
2. Export a PWM channel for use with sysfs.
3. Set the period (in nanoseconds)
4. Set the duty_cycle (in nanoseconds)
5. Enable the PWM signal

---

> The code below is testing code as part of my development process.
> All listed code works but has minimal error checking and may not be the most elegant or efficient.
> Only PWM0 code is listed but PWM1 also works (with appropriate changes).

The following script sets a single PWM output on pwm0 (pin12 GPIO18 or pin32 GPIO12).

```
#! /bin/sh
# Export channel 0
# Set the period 1,000,000 nS (1kHz)
# Set the duty_cycle 50%
# Enable the PWM signal
# 2023-07-06

cd /sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0
echo 0 > export
sleep 0.1
echo 10000000 > pwm0/period
echo  5000000 > pwm0/duty_cycle 
echo 1 > pwm0/enable
```

`echo 0 > /sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0/pwm0/enable` can be used to stop PWM.

---

I actually used a c program to setup both channels

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
//2023-07-05

#define PWM_SYSFS "/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0/"
#define PWM_PATH0 "/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0/pwm0/"
#define PWM_PATH1 "/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0/pwm1/"

void writeSYS(char filename[], char value[]){
    FILE* fp;           // create a file pointer fp
    fp = fopen(filename, "w");  // open file for writing
    fprintf(fp, "%s", value);   // send the value to the file
    fclose(fp);         // close the file using fp
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int chan = 0;
    writeSYS(PWM_SYSFS "export", "0");  // export PWM channel (0)
    writeSYS(PWM_SYSFS "export", "1");  // export PWM channel (1)

    usleep(100000);                 // sleep for 100ms
    writeSYS(PWM_PATH0 "period" , "1000000");   // set period
    writeSYS(PWM_PATH0 "duty_cycle" , "250000");    // set duty_cycle
    writeSYS(PWM_PATH0 "enable" , "1");     // enable
    writeSYS(PWM_PATH1 "period" , "50000");     // set period
    writeSYS(PWM_PATH1 "duty_cycle" , "25000"); // set duty_cycle
    writeSYS(PWM_PATH1 "enable" , "1");     // enable
}
```

---

To use the following python code on PWM1 change `pwm_channel = '1'`

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# 2023-07-09
"""
Export channel (0 or 1)
Set the period 1,000,000 ns (1kHz)
Set the duty_cycle 50%
Enable the PWM signal
"""
pwm_channel = '0'
PERIOD = 1000000 
DUTY_CYCLE =  PERIOD//2

import sys, os, time
PWM_SYSFS = "/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0"

if not os.path.isdir(PWM_SYSFS) :
    print("Overlay not loaded")
    exit()

pwm_dir = f"{PWM_SYSFS}/pwm{pwm_channel}"
if(not os.access(pwm_dir, os.F_OK)) :
    with open(f"{PWM_SYSFS}/export", "w") as f:
        f.write(f"{pwm_channel}\n")
    time.sleep(0.1)

with open(os.path.join(pwm_dir, "period"), "w") as f:
    f.write(f"{PERIOD}\n")
with open(os.path.join(pwm_dir, "duty_cycle"), "w") as f:
    f.write(f"{DUTY_CYCLE}\n")
with open(os.path.join(pwm_dir, "enable"), "w") as f:
    f.write("1\n")
```

---

> I have recently been advised that only the GPIO `sysfs` has been deprecated but the PWM `sysfs` interface is still supported.
> The `sysfs` has been deprecated and "replaced" by a userspace char device interface introduced with Linux 4.8 which is intended to replace the Sysfs interface `/sys/class/gpio`. Unfortunately this has limited functionality and is little used for gpio.
> As of kernel 6.1 `sysfs` remains but the possibility of its removal still exists. There seems to be no userspace functionality for PWM like I²C and SPI.