# How can I generate a hardware PWM on Raspberry Pi 4 using Python?

Tags: pi-4, pwm, pigpio, gpiozero

I need a PWM signal of 25KHz and duty cicle 0-100%. It must be "hardware" becase I don't want to bother the CPU with that. The ony way I found to do that in Python is by using `ppigpio` library. But I never used before and I don't know how to set it up. As far as I understand there is `true hardware pwm` and `hardware-timed pwm`. But I don't know which instructions stars on type and which starts the other. Can you show me a basic example ?

Edit: is this the right way to do it ?

```
import pigpio
import time

# Set the GPIO pin for PWM
gpio_pin = 18

# Set the PWM frequency (25 kHz)
pwm_frequency = 25000

# Set the PWM duty cycle (75%)
pwm_duty_cycle = 750000  # 75% of the range (0-1000000)

# Initialize the pigpio library
pi = pigpio.pi()

if not pi.connected:
    print("Unable to connect to pigpio daemon. Exiting.")
    exit()

try:
    # Set the PWM frequency and duty cycle using hardware_PWM
    pi.hardware_PWM(gpio_pin, pwm_frequency, pwm_duty_cycle)

    # Run the PWM for a certain duration (e.g., 10 seconds)
    time.sleep(10)

finally:
    # Stop PWM and cleanup
    pi.hardware_PWM(gpio_pin, 0, 0)  # Set duty cycle to 0 to stop PWM
    pi.stop()
```

Edit2: I also tried this, but it says "bad PWM frequency":

```
from gpiozero import PWMOutputDevice
import time

PWM_PIN = 18  # Change this to the GPIO pin you want to use
PWM_FREQUENCY = 25000  # 25 kHz
PWM_DUTY_CYCLE = 0.5  # 50%

pwm = PWMOutputDevice(PWM_PIN, frequency=PWM_FREQUENCY)

try:
  while True:
    print('Speed: 100 %')
    pwm.value = 1
    time.sleep(20)

    print('Speed: 50 %')
    pwm.value = 0.5
    time.sleep(20)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
  pass

finally:
  pwm.value = 0  # Set PWM duty cycle to 0
  print("\nProgram terminated by user. PWM stopped.")
```

Comment: Look at the [documentation](https://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#hardware_PWM).

Comment: @joan so all I have to do is `pi.hardware_PWM(18, 25000, 750000)` ? (I am a very beginer and I don't want to break something)

Comment: @joan, se my edit example, please... Is that ok ?

Comment: I started the `pigpiod` and it uses 2% of my CPU :( all the time... (without any command send to it)

Comment: It is somehow ironical, to search for a hardware solution so that the CPU remains free, and this library, which claims that use hardware, it does exactly the opposite and eats 2% of my CPU only when idle...

Comment: If pigpio is not suitable then use a different GPIO library.  Use the library most appropriate for your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several hardware PWM implementations (although it is doubtful that they will work on a Pi5). All that I am aware of directly manipulate the system registers.

There is a kernel overlay for PWM although it is poorly documented. I have written code to use this. See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/143644/8697

I have recently been tidying up the code for more general usage. See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/145068/8697